# Best practice to hide video url using Nginx proxy pass

Tags: nginx, proxypass

To protect my video, I managed to hide my video url using Nginx proxy pass like this:

```
location /video {
    proxy_pass https://myvideoserverfileserver.com/vod001.mp4;
}
```

As expected, I can play my video on a browser with this URL https://example.com/video.

Im not sure if ordinary users could reveal the real URL.

If so, there is any thing I can do more to level up protecting things like this?

Comment: How does hiding the original url "protect" your video?

Comment: @EsaJokinen What's I can do for the moment is protecting my original video url with proxy_pass  and I'm not sure if this would be the right approach!  considering this is the first level.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly is the objective with "hiding"? It looks like you want to simply change the filename, and that isn't really hiding...

Comment: @TeroKilkanen My intention is to do a custom logic such as jwt token verification and then serving video file. By using proxy pass or rewrite directives, user could not see the real url.  correct?

Comment: No, but how does that help? The file is still available via the rewritten URL, it doesn't care about any tokens.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen So, anything I could do please let me know.

Comment: It really depends what exact goal you have. If you want to allow only authenticated people access the video, then you need to implement a system that checks authentication data before sending video. It is easiest to implement this in your app.

Answer (score 2):

A [rewrite](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) would be less expensive in resources than a *reverse proxy*:

```
rewrite ^/video$ /vod001.mp4 break;
```

However, they are both only suitable for shortening or prettifying the URL, but they won't protect your video from downloads.

Comment: Thanks @Esa Jokinen  At least we can hide the real url with those approaches!

Could you please clarify if an ordinary user could reveal the real video url with browser or other tool?

Comment: Not unless you use the link somewhere else or a search engine indexes it. Or if the pattern is guessable from another video link. But if there's something sensitive in the filename, why not just change it? :)